# CSS And Other Few Elements Not Working In Express Website. Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, discord.js

I am making a discord bot with website, and i have defined css and other stuff in .html file but its still not showing when i go to the website.

```
         res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../../website/command.html"))
     })
```

Thats how i require the html file.

The Html File:

```
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Commandli</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/746706292562853888/0b578635739cbd7e5b076e65f2c04a4c.png?size=2048">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/commands.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <a href="../index.html" class="logo"><img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/"/> bot</a>
    <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
    <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="commands.html">Commands</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://">Invite bot</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="tabs">
      <div class="tab-header">
        <div class="tablink tab-active" onclick="openCity(event,'Utility')">Utility</div>
        <div class="tablink " onclick="openCity(event,'Fun')">Fun</div>
        <div class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Economy')">Economy</div>
        <div class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Info')">Info</div>
        <div class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Games')">Games</div>
        <div class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'Misc')">Misc</div>
        <div class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event,'All commands')">All commands</div>
      </div>
  
      <div style="margin-left:130px">
  
        <div id="Utility" class="tab-content category" style="display:block">
          <p><a>Utility commnads</a><br>Those commands help you with some things</p>
          <p><a>=dungeon</a><br>Sends information about the current dungeon.</p>
          <p><a>=help</a><br>Sends help!</p>
          <p><a>=gamepedia</a><br>Search what you want on gamepedia</p>
          <p><a>=welcome info</a><br>Information about the welcome system</p>
          <p><a>Soon more!</a><br>Stay tuned!</p>
        </div>

        
      </div>
  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/commands.js"></script>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML file in bin = https://sourceb.in/DEA1wBlvs2
(Had to remove some code because it was huge)

Comment: just to clarify, what isn't showing up? The entire page or just the CSS?

Comment: just the css and styles. the page loooks ugly

Comment: Did you expose those assets with [express.static](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html#serving-static-files-in-express) ? Otherwise the client won't be able to access those.